# Apply Text To Surface Question?

Tags: texturing, uv, text-object

How do I create this?[image]

I want to similarly add text to an old plank fence, but I don't want it to just look like an "overlay"

Comment: have you already made the plank texture? are the planks different objects? or different meshes within one object? maybe tell a bit more...

Comment: Using text may not yield a better result. Try unwrapping the object, design the text with transparent background in photo apps, and then do the overlaying in the **Texture** area

Comment: moonbots - the plank texture has been downloaded from CG textures, one image which is a plank fence.

Comment: Israel Bamidele - Somewhat new to this...could you give a little more detail to your suggestion?  I also have the text as a PNG image, with a transparent background.  Are you recommending unwrapping this onto the plank image?  I've tried that, but the text still appears as if it's simply overlayed.  I would like for the cracks/gaps in the planking to show through the text.  Hope that's more clear??

Answer (score 1):

We lack some informations about your current file, but the basic way to do it is this one:

- Unwrap your planks (*Smart UV Project* mode is good for this kind of object) and put your wood image texture on it with the following node organization:

[image]

- In your picture software (Photoshop, Krita or even Blender), create your text with an alpha transparency.

[image]

- Create a second UV Map and unwrap (*Project From View* mode) the front plank faces, those where the text is supposed to appear. You need this second UV Map because the first you've created won't fit.

[image]

- Now you need to mix your wood *Image Texture* with your text *Image Texture*. Create a second *Image Texture* and load the text picture.  Into the *Vector* input, plug an *Input* > *UVmap* node, and choose the second UVmap you've created so that the text will be displayed according it. Use a *Color* > *MixRGB* node to mix the 2 *Image Textures*. In the *Factor*, plug the *Alpha* output of the text *Image Texture* so that it lets all the transparent area display the wood.

[image]

- Of course it would need a bit more work, like creating a bump map and plugging it into your nodes *Normal* inputs to give your object a bit of 3D bumps...

Comment: Thanks, moonbots, for the quick reply!  My learning curve is immense, so I've copied your instructions and will work on it!  I understand the node setup, but have not worked with two UV maps yet, so I kind of got lost with that part.  Also, using Projecting with Smart UV Project confused me, but I'll keep working on it.  Thanks again!!

Comment: you can create and use as many UV maps as you want, if you create a new one, you'll have to use a UV map node, by default the other nodes will use the first UV map on the list I guess, but you can also plug another UV map node in the other Image Texture with the first UV map you created

Comment: Thanks again, moonboots.  That certainly did the trick!  If I can ever get my learning curve up to speed, I'll certainly try to pay it forward to others!  Have a good one!

Comment: you're welcome  ;)  nice if you understood verything